# Metro Application Issue with BackgroundTask NOT triggered

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, background-process, winrt-async

Without going into too much detail, here's the basic scenario.

I have a Metro App that downloads files off a server.

Once the files are downloaded, a `ListView` is updated in the **UI** with it's basic properties. If the user selects a `ListViewItem` from the `ListView`, it's `StorageFile` contents are displayed next to it. The user then takes some action based on the selected `StorageFile` content.

**Now for the design question:**

On `Suspending` or `Shutdown` - I would like the app to continue downloading files off the server, so I register for **2** `BackgroundTasks`. One is a `SystemTrigger`, which kicks off immediately and the other is a `TimeTrigger` that kicks off every **15** minutes. The `BackgroundTasks` also raise notifications, so that the user is aware that more files are available.

I `Register` these tasks when the `Suspending` event is raised (and on `Shutdown`). I `Unregister` these tasks when the `Resuming` event is raised or when the App is constructed from scratch. This ensures that either the **UI** or `BackgroundTask` is responsible for processing, and not both.

When testing this in Visual Studio, the `BackgroundTasks` work as expected. However, outside of Visual Studio the `BackgroundTasks` never seem to trigger. These `BackgroundTasks` request **Lock Screen** access, via `BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync().`

Is there a fundamental flaw in this design or am I missing something really simple? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In your testing, are you testing on a Surface RT? One thing that differs greatly between your development environment and consumption environment is the processing power, along with things like data usage limits. You could be running into either of these.

Comment: I'm currently testing from my PC.

Comment: Have you posted the app to your lock screen manually while not in the development environment? From the API: "The user must place your app on the lock screen before the app can use these background tasks. An app can request lock screen access by calling RequestAccessAsync. This presents a dialog box asking the user to "allow" or "don't allow" your app on the lock screen. An app is only allowed to ask for lock screen access once; any subsequent calls to RequestAccessAsync are ignored."

Comment: I apologize for continuing to 'go through the motions', just trying to make sure all the bases are covered. Have you ensured that the entry points in the Background Task Declaration point to the proper namespace and class of your Background Tasks? I know that many things work in my dev environment even if there is an issue with the app manifest (such as having incorrect logo image sizes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fundamental flaw in this design:

> I Register these tasks when the Suspending event is raised (and on
>   Shutdown). I Unregister these tasks when the Resuming event is raised.

This is **not** how BackgroudnTasks should be used. You should **register your tasks only once** and keep them registered, and once the task is started, **check if application is running** (using shared property in ApplicationSettings). If yes, just end the task, if not, to the downloading. Also note that background task will run only for about **two seconds each 15 minutes**. You cannot just download large data in these tasks, only check for new files, start BackgroundDownloader and/or show Toast notification.

> When testing this in Visual Studio, the BackgroundTasks work as
>   expected. However, outside of Visual Studio the BackgroundTasks never
>   seem to trigger. These BackgroundTasks request Lock Screen access, via
>   BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync().

First of all, are these tasks in separate library/project which is **Windows Runtime Component**? If not, then it won't work. Second, if your task requires lockscreen access, user must allow this execution in a dialog shown after the RequestAccessAsync call - this just won't work if you're registering the task in Suspending event.

Anyway, as I mentioned, for downloading large files you should use these classes:

```
StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(path, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(new Uri(filePath), file);
```

Let me know, if this helps or you need any more hints.